# Simplest Proof of Pierce's Law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove Pierce's Law in the simplest way possible.  Many of the proofs I've encountered utilize proof by cases, or distribution laws. I believe it can be done without.

What I am trying to show, formally, is the following: $ \{ ( A \to B ) \to A \} \vdash A $

using only basic rules of inference and the definition of the binary connectives.

The following proof is the best I could surmise, but it uses distribution, which I know can be avoided.

$ ( A \to B ) \to A $

$ \neg( A \to B ) \lor A $

$ ( A \land \neg B ) \lor A $

$ ( A \lor A ) \land ( A \lor \neg B ) ~~~ distribution ~ \text{what I want to avoid} $

$ A \lor A $

$ A $

Thank you!

Comment: This is vague. Please state exactly what you are allowed to use.

Comment: Modus Tollens/Ponens, Hypothetical/Disjunctive Syllogism, Contraposition, Join Rule (A, B \vdash A \land B), Double Negation, LEM.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the rules of propositional calculus.

If you may use the Law of Absorption, you may use it.

$${(A\wedge\neg B)\vee A~~\equiv~~ A}$$

Comment: unfortunately, can't use absorption. :(

Comment: (+1) Graham, answering this user is like chasing a moving target.  They tell you what you can't use only after you use it in an answer.  See, E.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592349/question-on-proof-of-a-lor-b-to-c-vdash-a-to-c.  Do you mean the OP is using rules of propositional calculus?

Comment: Why are you so harsh with me? I'm new at all of this and I'm struggling a lot.  Please have some consideration.

Comment: Yes...  Indeed, @amWhy.  Updated.

Comment: @Booth, you have responded to answers on two questions with, effectively, "No, I did not want to use *that*."  A more considerate approach would be to list rules available up front.